# Firebase Auth : Linking Anonymous Account

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

The documentation [Convert an anonymous account to a permanent account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account) indicates 3 steps to the process, however step 2 seems to violate step 1.

> 1. When the user signs up, complete the sign-in flow for the user's authentication provider **up to, but not including, calling one of the
>      Auth.signInWith methods**. For example, get the user's Google ID token,
>      Facebook access token, or email address and password.
> 2. Get an AuthCredential for the new authentication provider: `var credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
>      response.authResponse.accessToken);`
> 3. Pass the AuthCredential object to the sign-in user's link method...

My question is re: step 2. **`response`** exists only *after* calling one of the `Auth.signInWith` methods that step 1 says *not* to do.  How does one link an anonymous account with an oAuth account?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, the focumentation should read, "An anonymous user will be upgraded upon successful resolution of the `.linkWithPopup(provider)` method." That's all you gotta do. ...not sure what the existing steps shown above are all about.

Answer (score 5):

What the documentation says is that in step 1 you should **not sign in with Firebase**. What step 1 is saying is that you should **sign in with the provider** (i.e. Google, Facebook, Twitter), and then get the **provider token** and then **link the provider token to an existing Firebase anonymous account** or **sign in with Firebase using the provider token**. The important thing is that the token the documentation refers to comes from the provider, not Firebase.

You didn't specify in what language/platform you plan to do this, but here is just an example with Dart/Flutter:

```dart
GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
// Get the provider auth token
GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;     
FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
// Check if the user has signed in as anonymous
if (user != null) { 
  // Use the provider auth token to link the anonymous account
  await _auth.linkWithGoogleCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken, idToken: googleAuth.idToken);
} else if (user == null || user.email == null) {
  user = await _auth.signInWithGoogle(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken, 
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm using the web/javascript SDK. In my mind, the workflow scenario is (1) user is using my app w anonymous account. (2) my app offers ability to create (permanent) account.

Comment: This is so confusing.. 'Sign in with the provider' - what exactly is this?